# file() [function.file]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: php, chat

I got the following error when I get contents from file("http://www.otherdomain.com").

```
file() [function.file]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The domain server is linux.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 25):

Quoting:

> If you're having problems with fopen("url...") but you can run 'host
>   url' in a shell window and get the
>   correct lookup, here's why...
>
> This has had me banging my head
>   against it all day - finally I found
>   the answer buried in the bug reports,
>   but figured it should really be more
>   prominent!
>
> The problem happens when you're on an
>   ADSL line with DHCP (like our
>   office)... When the ADSL modem renews
>   the DHCP lease, you can also switch
>   DNS servers, which confuses apache
>   (and hence PHP) - meaning that you
>   can't look up hosts from within PHP,
>   even though you *can* from the
>   commandline.... The short-term
>   solution is to restart apache.
>
> You'll get "php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure
>   in name resolution in ..." messages as
>   symptoms. Restart apache, and they're
>   gone :-)
>
> Simon

[Comment by Simon at php.net](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#33228)

Comment: What exactly does `but you can run 'host url' in a shell window` mean? Like running `ping <site url>` from that site's server?

Comment: @doublejack: it means open Terminal in any Linux and type, e.g. "host google.com" :P

Answer (score 2):

make sure that website can be reached from you server.
also make sure that you are using has a proper DNS server setup.

if you are sure that website is working ... try modifying the /etc/hosts file and add the website's IP for test purposes, then try to figure out why it doesn't solve the domain.

Comment: yes, website is running properly. since last 4-5 days its given this warning :  
file() [function.file]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in %url% on line %lineno%

I did not find hosts file in etc in server. Please tell me how to create that

Answer (score 2):

The Domain can not be resolved to it's IP address.

If you have your DNS running local, try restarting it. If not, check your DNS or add a different server to /etc/resolve.conf (i.e. nameserver 8.8.8.8).

You can also add the domain as a static entry in your hosts file:

On your linux server add the DNS information to your /etc/hosts file using:

`echo '127.0.0.1 www.otherdomain.com' >> /etc/hosts`

…where 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of your website and www.otherdomain.com the domain name your using.

You can find the IP address of any domain using nslookup, i.e

`nslookup www.otherdomain.com`

Comment: Thank You,
my website is running properly. The problem is that emails are not going from my website and when i use file("http://otherdomain.com") it gives an error 
file() [function.file]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

And when I use file("http://otherdomainIP.com") if works fine.
Please help me to find out this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue with [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/) geocoding! Restarting Apache like Shehi recommended fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your internet connection. If the internet is down, this error occurs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31940501)